# Argument cannot be null. System null pointer exception for checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to pass checkbox value in parameter so when I am trying to use `checkboxval= Boolean.valueOf(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(checkboxval));` the null pointer exception is firing on this line. While previewing the page it is showing this error

Controller :

```
public class controllercls {
    public Boolean checkboxval;
    public controllercls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        record = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
        checkboxval = Boolean.valueOf(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('checkboxval')); // here I am getting Argument cannot be null exception

    }
    public PageReference method1() {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/otherpage?checkboxval='
            record.checkboxval__C);

    }
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="controllercls">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.checkboxval__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean.valueOf throws NullPointerException when the parameter is null. You need to check for null first:

```
String checkboxvalParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('checkboxval');
if(checkboxvalParam != null) {
    checkboxval = Boolean.valueOf(checkboxvalParam);
}
```

Or, depending on your preference, you might just assign a value based on if it's true (or false, whatever you prefer):

```
String checkboxvalParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('checkboxval');
checkboxval = checkboxvalParam == 'true';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are accepting any values from URL parameter where `checkboxval` is a key then use within the single quotes

```
checkboxval = Boolean.valueOf(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('checkboxval'));
```

Without the quote, it is trying to take dynamic value which you have declared as

```
public Boolean checkboxval;
```

And, at the time of accessing the value in `getParameters`, it is null. That's why you are facing NullPointer exception.

Comment: I added quotes but still it is showing same error